# Workflow - Three Conditions with Unique Approvers

Tags: 2013, workflow, approval, workflow-variable, workflow2013

How do I make a workflow with three scenarios?

The workflow is dependent on the value of the following:

1. Billing Information (2 possible values)
2. Request Type (4 possible values)
3. Business Unit (20 possible values)

Currently I only have two but I am confused what to do with these three.

Comment: could you please give more information about your scenarios